# Format python virtual environment name on bash prompt without root access

Tags: python, environment-variables, environment

Normally you would change simply PS1 in /bin/activate. Problem is the file is readonly. How would you do that from bash_profile, for example?

This is part of the /bin/activate file:

```
if [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT:-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="${PS1:-}"
    PS1="(python3.9.13_) ${PS1:-}"
    export PS1
fi
```

Comment: what `root` account got to do with your virtual environment?

Comment: I thought that was the reason I couldn't edit the /bin/activate file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your account isn't the owner of the `./venv/bin/activate` file (which usually has mode 644 on it). So you can't *edit* and/or *chmod* it unless you can become the file owner or root.

So what can you do... You can set a custom (PS1) prompt in your `~/.bash_profile` but this will be overwritten after sourcing the activate file unless you also set `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT` to something, e.g.:

```
export PS1="My prompt> "
export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1
```

This way your prompt won't change after you run `. bin/activate`. But the downside is that you won't see any changes in your prompt after running `activate` and `deactivate`.

If you want to set the prompt to something specific from your *virtual environment*/project, I would create a **function** in your `~/.bash_profile` instead that changes the prompt to what you want. For example to display the current (active) Python version in your prompt + the current path:

```
p() {
   export PS1="[$(python --version 2>&1)] \W "
}
```

Than you will simply have to enter `p` each time after activating a *virtual environment* and you will have your custom prompt.